# How can I visualize Flexible Discrimant Analysis as a biplot in R?

Tags: r, ggbiplot, linear-discriminant

I've read the paper of Gardner and Le Roux about [Extensions of Biplot Methodology to Discriminant Analysis](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00357-005-0006-7.pdf). I wanted to ask if someone got any practical experience with that method.
I've got a FDA model for a data set from kaggle Human Resources Analytics, available here [data set](https://uploadfiles.io/bsu80). I used the code

```
modFDA = train(left~. , data = train, method = 'fda', 
            tuneGrid = data.frame(degree = 1:10, nprune = 1:10),
            trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10, repeats = 5))
```

to fit the model. The training sample was chosen using

```
smp.size = floor(0.7*nrow(data))
set.seed(123)
train.ind = sample(seq_len(nrow(data)), size = smp.size)
train = data[train.ind,]
test = data[-train.ind,]
```

When I try using the `biplot` function I get an error for missing y values. I know there's a ggbiplot function but it only seems to work for LDA, since it requires linear discriminants for plotting. And I can't find those more precisely discriminant values in my model output. I seem to be missing something but I can't figure out what it is..

some more of my code

```
biplot(modFDA$finalModel)
```

returns missing y values.

Also tried to scale the data set

```
train_z = lapply(train, function(x) if (is.numeric(x)) scale(x) else x)
FDAfit = fda(left~., data = train_z)
df = fortify(FDAfit, train_z)
```

tried to fit an ggplot using an example on the iris data but using LDA, but don't know what to use for `aes`. also there seems to be no function named geom_axis

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = (LD1)?, y = (LD2)?)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = left)) + 
  stat_ellipse(aes(group = left, color = left)) +
  geom_axis(data = attr(df, "basis"), aes(label = abbreviate(.name))) + 
  coord_equal()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the name of the R package that allows users to download the `train` data and call the function.

Comment: I've downloaded it from kaggle and then just used `read.csv` but I've made it available here: [data] (https://ufile.io/bsu80). for the biplot I simply used `biplot(modFDA$finalModel)`